# Facebook share - HTML in og:description tag

Tags: facebook

Can we have html links in og:description tag? If not is there any work around please?

Comment: No it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can't put hyperlinks inside the `og:description` tag, unfortunately. You can use an HTML link in the `og:url` tag, like so: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com">`

Comment: So there is no way Facebook can have hyperlinks in post?

Comment: @SachinNaik Unfortunately not.

Comment: _Fortunately_ not, I’d say - because that surely would be abused to no end by the usual spammer ftard crowd out there. Beside, you *already* posted a link. Description means description of the content behind that link - not further links nested into it.